# How to fit regression line to plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression

So I have this plot that looks like this:

[image]

Both the x and y axis are log, how do I fit a least squares regression line to this? This is what I used to plot the graph:     plot(log(counts),log="x",type="p")

counts contains the number of observations of each x...

Answer (score 6):

The least squares regression for log(counts) on log(x) is simply:

```
lm(log(counts) ~ log(x))
```

If you want to plot it:

```
plot(log(counts) ~ log(x))
abline(reg=lm(log(counts) ~ log(x)))
```

This may not be the most statistically appropriate model for your data, but that's a question for another site....

Comment: the thing is that I really don't have an x vector, I only have counts

Comment: how do I plot the regression line using only counts?

Comment: You must have an x variable lurking somewhere. Let me guess: `counts` is the result of calling `table` on something. If so, use the names of the result as your x.

Comment: To anticipate the next question: you'll need to turn the names of your table into numeric, with `as.numeric`.

Comment: you right, I was using this: counts <- table(abs(NewDataOrds)) to make counts. But when I try plotting this: plot(log(counts) ~ log(unique(abs(NewDataOrds)))), it doesnt work because for some reason counts has one less element...